# Is there an analog of Robin's Inequality for L-functions?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

In his 1984 paper Guy Robin showed the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to $\sigma(n)\lt e^\gamma n\log\log n$ for all integers  $\gt$  5040.

The Riemann Zeta Function is a special type of L-function which are defined here http://www.lmfdb.org/intro/zetatour

Is there an analog of Robin’s Inequality for a general L-function?

Comment: Try adapting [Nicolas paper](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/nicolas/petitsphi83.pdf) to Dirichlet L-functions and $\prod_{p \le x} (1-\chi(p) p^{-1})$